# Attributes of another jQuery plugin instance getting overridden

Tags: jquery, plugins, attributes, overriding, instance

I'm having this weird problem where other instances of my jQuery plugin are getting modified even though I believe I've written my plugin to support multiple separate instances.

I've stripped down the code to the bare essentials, and you can test it out here: http://jsbin.com/ajifoh/4/edit#html,live

The first time you press a key in either textbox it should display `leng: 0` in the console, but after you've triggered the first one for some reason the second one also has all the comboParts that were inserted for the first... What have I done wrong?

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

  var KeyCombinator = function( elem, options ){
      this.$elem = $(elem);
    };

  function ComboPart(keyCode){
    if (keyCode !== undefined){
      this.keyCode = keyCode;
    }
  }
  function ComboData(){
    this.comboParts= [];
  }

  function set_insert(array, value){
    array.push(value);
  }

  KeyCombinator.prototype = {
    comboData: new ComboData(),

    eval_key_event: function(e){
      set_insert(this.comboData.comboParts, new ComboPart(e.keyCode));
    },

    init: function(){
      var $elem = this.$elem;
      var that = this;

      $elem.keydown(function(e){
        console.log('leng', that.comboData.comboParts.length);
        that.eval_key_event(e);
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn.makeKeyCombinator = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new KeyCombinator(this, options).init();
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties added to the `prototype` only exists once per type. Since you instantiate `ComboData` on the `KeyCombinator.prototype`, all instances of `KeyCombinator` share a single instance of `ComboData`. If you want a unique instance of `ComboData` for each instance of `KeyCombinator`, you need to instantiate it in your `KeyCombinator` constructor as such:

```
var KeyCombinator = function( elem, options ){
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.comboData = new ComboData();
};
```

Here is a working example in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajifoh/5/).